# How can i access $toast in Nuxt vuex store

Tags: typescript, vuex, nuxt.js, toast

i have `@nuxtjs/toast` installed and working properly in my application.

I want to show a toast after an action is dispatched.
How can i access `$toast` in my actions in my module in the vuex store?

PS: i am using Nuxt with typescript, and from intellisense it seems i can only access $router and $axios.

```
export const actions: ActionTree<ProfileState, RootState> = {
async updateProfile({ }, user) {
    console.log(user);
    const newUserObj = await this.$axios.post("/me/update", user).then(res => res.data.data);

    console.log(newUserObj);
    // this.$toast.info("Hello");

    // commit('LOAD_NEW_USER', newUserObj);
},
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, lets fix your action

```
async updateProfile({commit}, user) {
    return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
      try {
        const newUserObj = await this.$axios.$post("/me/update", user)
        commit('SET_USER',newUserObj)
        resolve(newUserObj)
        
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error)
      }
     
    })
  },
```

To show the toast-

Try `this.app.$toast` below the line `commit('SET_USER',newUserObj)`

Comment: Thanks. worked like a charm,
and for pointing out the refactor

Comment: @useruser8254635 what if i wanted to access it in the mutation? what do i do?

Comment: I suppose it'll work the same way mentioned above but you shouldn't be setting toasts from vuex. Show toast it in pages or components after your action promise resolves or rejects.

Comment: @useruser8254635 it doesn't work the same way apparently. And i'm not using it to set toast. I'm trying to access this.$auth i'm using @nuxt/auth